# What does <Component render={({ state }) => {}} /> do in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullpage.js

I am currently learning ReactJS, and i wanted to use fullPageJS. It's working correctly, but there is some of the syntax that i don't quite get.

The component:

```
   function home() {
    return (
        <ReactFullpage
            render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
            return (
                <ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
                    <div className="section">
                        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="section">
                        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
                    </div>
                </ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
            );
            }}
        />
    )
}
export default home;
```

Now my question, what does `render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => { return(); }} />` do? I can see that it is a property, but i don't really get what it's use is.

Comment: Read the official docs about it. [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pattern known as a Render Prop. It's a way to decide what to render via some two-way communication between your code and the code in ReactFullpage.

You pass a function in as one of the props. That alone a fairly common thing to do, such as passing in a function to an onClick prop. What's special here is how that function gets used.

While ReactFullpage is rendering, it will call your function. It's basically saying "hey, here's some data (the state and fullPageApi). What would you like me to render based on that data?" Your function then calculates and returns the elements you want it to render. And then ReactFullpage will use those elements in its final output.

For more information on render props, see [react's documentation on the pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

In react, render is a method that tell react what to display( what the DOM should look like) . Return in a method or function is the output of the method or function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning React! But since your question is just JS related, here's your answer.
First, let's put your snippet in pieces.

```
render={ ({ state, fullpageApi }) => { return (/** HTML */); } }
```

`render=` is XML, we con't care about it. It is HTML: you're passing a property to the `Component` element. The brackets `{}` indicate that it's JS in the HTML code: it means that you're giving JS values to the element's `render` property. The remaining JS code that was between the `{}` is:

```js
({ state, fullpageApi }) => { return (/** HTML */); }
```

Which is a function! So the `render` prop takes a function that'll probably get executed later.

This anonymous function takes an object as a parameter, but it *destructures* it and only uses the `state` and `fullpageAPI` props, which makes it possible to use them as variables: instead of writing `obj.state`, you'd write `state`, as an example. [You can read more about restructuring on the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It then `return`s the XML in the parenthesis.

Comment: Not XML, but JSX syntax.

Comment: @Bergi This is XML. This is the syntax HTML uses, with `<elem prop="value" />` HTML is XML. All JSX does is allow to write XML *in* JS.

Comment: But `<tag attr={…} />` or `<tag {...attrs}>` are features that are definitely not part of XML. Of course JSX is inspired by SGML and its derivates, but it's not the same.

Comment: You're totally right, but the JS part into brackets wasn't mentioned, I simply took the `render=`, not the `{}` which came after. It could have been a string as well, it doesn't really matter; this part was XML.